# How to build STAC of local raster files?

Tags: stac

How to build a [stac](/questions/tagged/stac) index for geotiff and other rasters on local file systems and Windows server shares? It would later be consumed by something like [stac-browser](https://github.com/radiantearth/stac-browser)

Answer (score 2):

Two tools that produce STAC items from geotiffs are:

- [rio-stac](https://github.com/developmentseed/rio-stac)
- [stactools' `create-item`](https://stactools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#stac-create-item)

**rio-stac** is more feature-ful and customizable, **stactools** is simpler. Here's an example of using and installing **rio-stac**:

```shell
pip install rio-stac
rio stac tests/fixtures/dataset_cog.tif
```

The STAC item will be printed to standard output.

If your geotiffs are from an open geospatial data provider, it might be worth checking https://github.com/stactools-packages/ to see if there's a repository for your dataset already created. **stactools-packages** can provide richer STAC items and collections that what could be created from the geotiffs alone.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct: rio-stac would handle 'add item to the stac', but doesn't address identifying items to add, or creating and hosting the catalog to add to. So one step out of three (and maybe more?).

Comment: `rio-stac` (or **stactools** `create-item`) would create a [STAC Item](https://github.com/radiantearth/stac-spec/blob/master/item-spec/item-spec.md) for a geospatial raster. To browse a many items with a tool like **stac-browser**, you would need to add your items to a collection. There's many examples of this in the **stactools-packages** Github organization -- [here's one for ASTER](https://github.com/stactools-packages/aster/blob/main/scripts/create_examples.py). You could also create your collection by hand by writing the JSON file yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on stactools-packages Pete. This is imagery we've purchased from various vendors over 20 years, so no there isn't an existing repository we can leverage unfortunately. We are building from ground up.

Comment: The STAC ecosystem seems very much python centered. Would be great to see other options in the future as well.

Comment: @jenswiesehahn there's some other language supported:
- JS/Node implementations: https://github.com/stac-utils/?q=&type=all&language=javascript&sort=
- Rust: https://github.com/stac-utils/?q=&type=all&language=rust&sort=
- And there's some .NET and others out there as well

However, most of the funding has come from projects that use Python.